# RestController required a service bean with spring boot & multi modules

Tags: spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I tested my spring boot project as a single maven project and all worked fine.
I decided to split my application into submodules.  repository, serive and the spring boot web module. The autowired stop working.
And the following bug occured :

```
20:12:08.052 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.plendo.service.interfaces.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
20:12:08.068 [main] WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
20:12:08.243 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - ``
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field userService in org.plendo.ui.controller.UserRestController required a bean of type 'org.plendo.service.interfaces.UserService' that could not be found.
```

Comment: That's not enough information. Did you e.g. change your package structure? What does your project structure and config classes look like now?

Answer (score 1):

The project structure :parent project that contains jpa module, service module and web module (spring boot app)

- spring boot application class : web module

  ```
  package org.plendo.ui;     
  @SpringBootApplication public class App { public static void main(String[] args) { 
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
      }
  ```
- RestController class : web module

  ```
  package org.plendo.ui.controller;
  import org.plendo.jpa.entity.User;

  import org.plendo.service.interfaces.UserService;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

  @RestController
  //@ComponentScan("org.plendo.service.interfaces")
  public class UserRestController {

  @Autowired
  //@Qualifier("userService")
  private UserService userService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser")
  public User saveUser(User u) {
      return userService.saveUser(u);
  }
  }
  ```
- UserServiceImpl : service module

  ```
  import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
  import org.plendo.jpa.entity.User;
  import org.plendo.jpa.entity.UserRepository;
  import org.plendo.service.interfaces.UserService;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

  @Service
  public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

  private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public User saveUser(User u) {
      return userRepository.save(u);
  }
  ```

  }
- UserService interface: service module

  ```
  package org.plendo.service.interfaces;

  import org.plendo.jpa.entity.User;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

  public interface UserService {

  public User saveUser(User u);
  }
  ```
- UserRepository interface: jpa module

  ```
  package org.plendo.jpa.entity;

  import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

  public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<User, String>{

  }
  ```

  There is some else to do ?